# Run multiple commands after pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, command

I am piping streamer ouput to mpv player which works fine.

```
streamer -o -  |  mpv -
```

But before starting mpv , I want to kill one program and then pipe to mpv.

streamer program takes some time to buffer video and after 10-15 seconds, it sends to mpv.   In those 10-15 seconds, I want to show screen_saver and then kill it just when streamer starts sending to mpv.

Below command just kills the screen_saver but does not run mpv.

```
streamer -o -  | pkill screen_saver ;  mpv -
```

Answer (score 2):

```
streamer -o -  | { dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; pkill screen_saver; cat; } | mpv -
```

The first byte from `streamer` is captured by `dd` and goes through beyond `}`. `dd` immediately terminates, `pkill` runs, then everything else goes through `cat`. All the stream should get to `mpv`.

This requires `pkill` to be silent on its stdout and read nothing from `streamer`. My `pkill` is like that. Just in case you may want to make sure: `</dev/null pkill screen_saver >/dev/null`.

---

To test the idea with common tools, run:

```
cat | { dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; echo "triggered" >&2; cat; } | cat
```

and type something (the first `cat` will probably get anything only after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). You will see `triggered<newline>` inserted just after the first byte of your input. Note this string doesn't disturb the stream the last `cat` gets, because it's printed to stderr; it's here just to show the triggering occurs when you need it.

Keep in mind `dd` works with bytes, so if the first character you type is multi-byte (e.g. `ś` in UTF-8) then the output may surprise you (because your console handles and *interlaces* stdout and stderr of the commands). This only means the triggering occurred mid-character, just after the first *byte*, exactly as designed.